# loadrunner winsocket send special characters in buffer ~

Tags: character, buffer, loadrunner, winsockets

I am working on a loadrunner winsocket script.

The buff that should be sent has a special character "~", when loadrunner sends the request it sends it as "~7e".

Request to be sent - FBE442757F3FA860~1cFFFF0222050017200181

Request that is sent to the application - FBE442757F3FA860~7e1cFFFF0222050017200181

How can we accommodate special characters in loadrunner winsocket.

Answer (score 0):

see lr_set_send_buffer() for how you can set the contents of any buffer.   I refer to your C programming expertise on construction of the buffer with embedded hex characters.

Comment: Thanks James. Yes, i tried to send the string request in HEX format and noticed the same behavior. Except for ~ character, all other special characters are being covered to Hex and sent to the server as required."~" is being converted to "~7e" even if it is sent as Hex string.